# Wordpress MU main sub-domain page not working, all other pages working

Tags: wordpress

I'm testing out the Wordpress Network/Multiple Blog setup by turning on the feature in WordPress 3.0, but I've hit a problem.

I added the necessary code to the .htaccess file and wp-config, and I added the wildcard into cPanel (and with the registrar), and the admin area works fine, as do individual pages and stories, but the home page won't load.

Any suggestions?

The error page I get is the server's default error page which says "Default Website Page".

Home page: http://test.celebuscope.com/
Working inside article: http://test.celebuscope.com/2011/11/04/hello-world/

**UPDATE:** I gave up trying to fix the problem, but I suspect the issue is related to the base domain (www. versus none). I deleted the install and started from scratch and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the /test/ folder on the server.

When you added subomains, the server mad ea folder, which overrides the virtual ones.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a /test/ folder in my server structure.

Comment: never seen the www do that before.